# jquery ui autocomplete on focus: item is not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i use jquery-ui's autocomplete in my project (v1.12.1). The only one issue is, that when i hover on a autocomplete item it throws an error:

> TypeError: item is undefined

the select event works well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: WP.autocompleteUrl + "?action=autocomplete",
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Y");
            return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return jQuery("<li>").data("item-autocomplete-item", item).data("url", item.url).append("<div>" + item.name + "</div>").appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should do some changes described here :**

[[Jquery Autocomplete Select TypeError: ui.item undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886104/jquery-autocomplete-select-typeerror-ui-item-undefined]Jquery[1])