# Jquery UI Autocomplete Custom HTML (TypeError: t.item is undefined)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I try to use jQuery UI Autocomplete function to show some data and select it.
But I see some error in the console
 I get a javascript error (item is undefined).
My code is

jq version:
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
jq-ui version:
jquery-1.10.2.min.js

```
 $("#searchterms").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: '@(Url.RouteUrl("OrderSkuSearch"))',
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#searchterms").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#productid").val(ui.item.id);
                console.log("focus: " + ui.item.id);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#searchterms").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#productid").val(ui.item.id);
                console.log("select: " + ui.item.id);
                return false;
            },

            autoFocus: true,
            delay: 3000

        })
            .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                //if ($("#productid").val() == "") {
                //    $("#productid").val(item.id);
                //}
                $("#productid").val(item.id);
                return $("<li>")
                .append("<a>" + item.value + ">" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            };
```

The return type is list:

```
[{"label":"Build your own computer","value":"COMP_CUST","id":1}]
```

Comment: Unsure where the issue is, yet I see `.append("<a>" + item.value + ">" + item.label + "</a>")` and this does not make proper HTML Syntax. Would suggest you provide an example of the data returned by your URL when query is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  var terms = [{
    label: "Label 1",
    value: "Value 1",
    id: 1001
  }, {
    label: "Label 2",
    value: "Value 2",
    id: 1002
  }, {
    label: "Label 3",
    value: "Value 3",
    id: 1003
  }];

  $("#searchterms").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: terms,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      $("#searchterms").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#productid").val(ui.item.id);
      console.log("focus: " + ui.item.id);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#searchterms").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#productid").val(ui.item.id);
      console.log("select: " + ui.item.id);
      return false;
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 3000
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="searchterms">Search: </label>
  <input type="text" id="searchterms" />
  <input type="text" id="productid" />
</div>
```

This seems to do what you want, yet I am not sure what Link you're trying to create.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try the version jquery 3.3.1 and jquery ui 1.12.1 with the extension renderItem. The ui.item still undefined. @Twisty

Comment: Please clarify why you're trying to render the item in that way. It's not making sense. @XIANYU

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913702/jquery-autocomplete-ui-item-undefined-using-instance-option

The case was similar with mine.

Comment: ,I wanna do some code snippet, because  I have to customize the return type.

Comment: @XIANYU this is managed in the `select` callback. The function for render items is just how the items are created, not what is done with them.